# How can I call list of ec2 instance based on the app code using tag method

Tags: amazon-ec2, boto3

I am trying to get all the instance(server name) ID based on the app.  Let's say I have an app in the server. How do I know which apps below to which server. I want my code to find all the instance (server) that belongs to each app. Is there any way to look through the app in the ec2 console and figure out the servers are associated with the app. More of using tag method

```
  import boto3

   client = boto3.client('ec2')


   my_instance = 'i-xxxxxxxx'
```

Comment: I am confusing, what is the APP?

Comment: Your question is rather confusing. Could you please edit your question to add more details? For example, what do you mean by "get all the ec2 instance based on the app"? Also, what do you mean by "all the instance that belongs to xyz"? It isn't clear what you mean when you say "how do I find the app".

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I did. Let me know if you have more questions

Comment: @Lamanus I meant to ask tag. I want to get the list based on the tag. I edited my question. Can you please remove the -feed back

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I meant to ask tag. I want to get the list based on the tag. I edited my question. Can you please remove the -feed back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Disclaimer: I work for AWS Resource Groups)

Seeing your comments that you use tags for all apps, you can use AWS Resource Groups to create a group - the example below assumes you used `App:Something` as tag, first creates a Resource Group, and then lists all the members of that group.

Using this group, you can for example get automatically a [CloudWatch dashboard](https://console.aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch/home?region=us-east-1#cw:filters=~(~(type~'ResourceGroup~params~'Something-App-Instances))) for those resources, or [use this group as a target in RunCommand](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/08/now-select-resource-groups-as-targets-for-aws-systems-manager-run-command/).

```py
import json
import boto3

RG = boto3.client('resource-groups')

RG.create_group(
  Name = 'Something-App-Instances',
  Description = 'EC2 Instances for Something App',
  ResourceQuery = {
    'Type': 'TAG_FILTERS_1_0',
    'Query': json.dumps({
      'ResourceTypeFilters': ['AWS::EC2::Instance'],
      'TagFilters': [{
        'Key': 'App',
        'Values': ['Something']
      }]
    })
  },
  Tags = {
    'App': 'Something'
  }
)

# List all resources in a group using a paginator
paginator = RG.get_paginator('list_group_resources')
resource_pages = paginator.paginate(GroupName = 'Something-App-Instances')
for page in resource_pages:
  for resource in page['ResourceIdentifiers']:
    print(resource['ResourceType'] + ': ' + resource['ResourceArn'])
```

Another option to just get the list without saving it as a group would be to directly use the [Resource Groups Tagging API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/resourcegroupstagging/latest/APIReference/API_GetResources.html)

Answer (score 0):

What you install on an Amazon EC2 instance is totally up to you. You do this by running code on the instance itself. AWS is not involved in the decision of what you install on the instance, **nor does it know what you installed on an instance**.

Therefore, you will need to keep track of "what apps are installed on what server" yourself.

You might choose to take advantage of **Tags** on instances to add some metadata, such as the purpose of the server. You could also use **AWS Systems Manager** to run commands on instances (eg to install software) or even use **AWS CodeDeploy** to roll-out software to fleets of servers.

However, even with all of these deployment options, AWS cannot track what you have put on each individual server. You will need to do that yourself.

**Update:** You can use [AWS Resource Groups](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ARG/latest/userguide/welcome.html) to view/manage resources by tag.

Here's some sample Python code to list tags by instance:

```py
import boto3

ec2_resource = boto3.resource('ec2', region_name='ap-southeast-2')

instances = ec2_resource.instances.all()

for instance in instances:
    for tag in instance.tags:
        print(instance.instance_id, tag['Key'], tag['Value'])
```

Comment: I used tags for all my apps. Can I get list of all the instance based on the tags. Is there way to do it.

Comment: So you're wanting a list of all instances that have a particular tag? Yes, this can be done. Do you want to use the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) or do it via Python?

Comment: Do it by boto3 python